# Android Studio: Issue with navigation xml editing and design view

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, navigation

We've been using the Navigation component in our project but have stumbled across an issue which seems unique to our project and the JetBrains Android plugin. I can't pinpoint the exact point it started happening but I noticed it after the release of AS 3.2.

The project builds fine however when editing a navigation XML things such as auto-complete and highlighting are broken and the Android Support Plugin throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$TypeRef@0=org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$NavigatorKeyInfo@17d69e53 and org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$TypeRef@0=org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$NavigatorKeyInfo@442c4fde
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.conflictException(ImmutableMap.java:215)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:209)
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.checkNoConflictInKeyBucket(RegularImmutableMap.java:147)
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.fromEntryArray(RegularImmutableMap.java:110)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:393)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema.buildCacheKeys(NavigationSchema.java:488)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema.init(NavigationSchema.java:479)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema.createIfNecessary(NavigationSchema.java:389)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AttributeProcessingUtil.processNavAttributes(AttributeProcessingUtil.java:408)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AttributeProcessingUtil.processAttributes(AttributeProcessingUtil.java:596)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomExtender.registerExtensions(AndroidDomExtender.java:57)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomExtender.registerExtensions(AndroidDomExtender.java:29)
at com.intellij.util.xml.reflect.DomExtenderEP.extend(DomExtenderEP.java:83)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.runDomExtenders(DynamicGenericInfo.java:134)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.lambda$checkInitialized$0(DynamicGenericInfo.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$2.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:98)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.checkInitialized(DynamicGenericInfo.java:63)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.getAttributeChildrenDescriptions(DynamicGenericInfo.java:241)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.processAttributeChildrenDescriptions(DynamicGenericInfo.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomSemContributor.lambda$registerSemProviders$5(DomSemContributor.java:199)
at com.intellij.semantic.SemServiceImpl$2.lambda$registerSemElementProvider$0(SemServiceImpl.java:93)
at com.intellij.semantic.SemServiceImpl.createSemElements(SemServiceImpl.java:190)
at com.intellij.semantic.SemServiceImpl.getSemElements(SemServiceImpl.java:161)
at com.intellij.semantic.SemService.getSemElement(SemService.java:37)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomManagerImpl.getDomHandler(DomManagerImpl.java:390)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GenericValueReferenceProvider.getReferencesByElement(GenericValueReferenceProvider.java:47)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.getReferences(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:135)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.mapNotEmptyReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:123)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.doGetReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:102)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:50)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:44)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeValueImpl.getReferences(XmlAttributeValueImpl.java:110)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.checkReferences(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:439)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.visitXmlAttributeValue(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:406)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeValueImpl.accept(XmlAttributeValueImpl.java:61)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.visit(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:587)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.runVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:353)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.lambda$collectHighlights$5(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:286)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:313)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.lambda$analyzeByVisitors$6(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:316)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.analyze(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:597)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:316)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.lambda$analyzeByVisitors$6(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:316)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.analyze(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:71)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:316)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectHighlights(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:283)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectInformationWithProgress(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:227)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:84)
at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:69)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:423)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1171)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:416)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:415)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:391)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:147)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:222)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:389)
at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:161)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

We're running the latest version of the navigation component (2.0.0-rc2) and and I've tried all the usual fixes (Invalidate Caches & Restart etc). I've tried using navigation in fresh projects and it seems to work without this error being thrown.

I have tried removing all nav XMLs from our project and then adding in a completely blank XML but it still throws the error. I delved into the source of the plugin and it seems this occurs when the plugin is initially processing the nav file for the design view which doesn't make sense if it's throwing it for a fresh nav file.

I'm currently at a loss as to why this may be happening and any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah I am getting the same thing and I also recently started using 2.0.0 (upgrading from the non-androidx).  It is happening for even the simplest navigation files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The short answer:**

I fixed it by moving an anonymous class which extended `androidx.navigation.Navigator` to a separate class and adding the annotation `@Navigator.Name(String name)` with a unique name.

If you are also experiencing this issue check that in your project or its dependencies if there are any classes inheriting the `Navigator` class which are either missing the `@Navigator.Name(String name)` annotation or using non-unique strings as the `name` parameter. `fragment` and `activity` cannot be used as they are used already within the API.

**Further info:**

After further delving into the Android Support plugin source code to understand what's going on I've managed to solve the issue on our project.

When initiating the IDE functionality in the Android Support Plugin it goes through your project and any dependencies looking for any class which inherits the `Navigator` class and gives it a tag for the purpose of managing it in the XML files and design view. This tag is based on an annotation `@Navigator.Name(String name)`. If no annotation is present a default value is used.

These tags have to be unique as they are used as the keys for building an immutable map of tags to navigator types. In our project we had an anonymous class which was extending `Navigator` class and had no annotation.

There is also an anonymous class extending `Navigator` within the navigation component source, specifically within the `NavDeepLinkBuilder` class. As there is only a single default value for the tags any other class inheriting `Navigator` with no annotation being present in your project or its dependencies will cause this issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, in my case, I'm not using any anonymous class which extended androidx.navigation.Navigator. Deleted all the nav_graphs, cleared cache, no use. :(

Comment: The issue disappeared after trying in AS 3.5 RC2.

Comment: I am not using any classes that inherit from Navigator (as far as I know).  The only one that could possibly be, I added the annotation to, and it still gets the error.  Any idea how I might fix that?

Comment: I just updated to AS 3.5 RC2 and that did actually fix the issue for me.  Thanks @AbhiMuktheeswarar