# IDE error when creating navigation resource file

Tags: android, android-studio

I just created the navigation resource directory for my app, but when I go to add a navigation resource file to it (New > Navigation resource file), I get an IDE error with this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$TypeRef@e0d67273=org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$NavigatorKeyInfo@340f65b2 and org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$TypeRef@e0d67273=org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema$NavigatorKeyInfo@4e3d0a2
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.conflictException(ImmutableMap.java:215)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:209)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.checkNoConflictInKeyBucket(RegularImmutableMap.java:147)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.fromEntryArray(RegularImmutableMap.java:110)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:393)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema.buildCacheKeys(NavigationSchema.java:475)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema.init(NavigationSchema.java:466)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.navigation.NavigationSchema.createIfNecessary(NavigationSchema.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.naveditor.surface.NavDesignSurface.lambda$tryToCreateSchema$3(NavDesignSurface.java:370)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.lambda$runReadActionInSmartMode$0(DumbService.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.lambda$runReadActionInSmartMode$1(DumbService.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:977)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:79)
    at com.android.tools.idea.naveditor.surface.NavDesignSurface.tryToCreateSchema(NavDesignSurface.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.naveditor.surface.NavDesignSurface.lambda$goingToSetModel$0(NavDesignSurface.java:278)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This isn't something I've ever seen before, does anyone know what might be causing it?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55532214/5825949

Comment: @ianhanniballake I was on 3.4.1, then updated to 3.4.2 and it's still happening

Comment: @himangi I only have one class that is using any kind of Navigation (and it isn't using Navigator, like that question suggests), and even after the annotation it gets the error.  Any ideas?